# Scanner method to get a char

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner

What is the `Scanner` method to get a `char` returned by the keyboard in Java.

like `nextLine()` for `String`, `nextInt()` for `int`, etc.

Comment: So turns out there is no built in method.
I ended up doing

String str = kb.nextLine();
char c = str.charAt(0);

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get a `char` from a `Scanner`, you can use the `findInLine` method.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("abc");
    char ch = sc.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    System.out.println(ch); // prints "a"
    System.out.println(sc.next()); // prints "bc"
```

If you need a bunch of `char` from a `Scanner`, then it may be more convenient to (perhaps temporarily) change the delimiter to the empty string. This will make `next()` returns a length-1 string every time.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("abc");
    sc.useDelimiter("");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    } // prints "a", "b", "c"
```

Comment: @poly : default Delimiter would be (`" "`)...? how to set that back? is this the suggested way -asking because this one is hell easy then all other given solutions on SO!!

Comment: `findInLine(".")`will not match newlines. The second approach does.

Comment: why use `findInLine(".");` I can get input by this `Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        char a;
        a=in.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(a);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Console API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) (which made its appearance in Java 6) as follows:

```
Console cons = System.console();
if(cons != null) {
  char c = (char) cons.reader().read();  // Checking for EOF omitted
  ...
}
```

If you just need a single line you don't even need to go through the reader object:

```
String s = cons.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Java's Scanner class does not have a built in method to read from a Scanner character-by-character.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

However, it should still be possible to fetch individual characters from the Scanner as follows:

```
Scanner sc:

char c = sc.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
```

And you could use it to fetch each character in your scanner like this:

```
while(sc.hasNext()){
    char c = sc.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    System.out.println(c); //to print out every char in the scanner
}
```

The findInLine() method searches through your scanner and returns the first String that matches the regular expression you give it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console cons = System.console();
```

The above code line creates cons as a null reference. The code and output are given below:

```
Console cons = System.console();
if (cons != null) {
    System.out.println("Enter single character: ");
    char c = (char) cons.reader().read();
    System.out.println(c);
}else{
    System.out.println(cons);
}
```

Output :

> null

The code was tested on macbook pro with java version "1.6.0_37"

Answer (score 0):

sc.next().charat(0).........is the method of entering character by user based on the number entered at the run time

example:
sc.next().charat(2)------------>>>>>>>>

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in)
char c = sc.next().trim().charAt(0);
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your code. What does this answer add over the already existing and accepted answers?