# Java Scanner newline parsing with regex (Bug?)

Tags: java, regex, newline, java.util.scanner

I'm developing a syntax analyzer by hand in Java, and I'd like to use regex's to parse the various token types. The problem is that I'd also like to be able to accurately report the current line number, if the input doesn't conform to the syntax.

Long story short, I've run into a problem when I try to actually match a newline with the Scanner class. To be specific, when I try to match a newline with a pattern using the Scanner class, it fails. Almost always. But when I perform the same matching using a Matcher and the same source string, it retrieves the newline exactly as you'd expect it too. Is there a reason for this, that I can't seem to discover, or is this a bug, as I suspect?

FYI: I was unable to find a bug in the Sun database that describes this issue, so if it is a bug, it hasn't been reported.

Example Code:

```
Pattern newLinePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\r\\n?|\\n)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
String sourceString = "\r\n\n\r\r\n\n";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(sourceString);
scan.useDelimiter("");
int count = 0;
while (scan.hasNext(newLinePattern)) {
    scan.next(newLinePattern);
    count++;
}
System.out.println("found "+count+" newlines"); // finds 7 newlines
Matcher match = newLinePattern.matcher(sourceString);
count = 0;
while (match.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println("found "+count+" newlines"); // finds 5 newlines
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `useDelimiter()` and `next()` combo is faulty. `useDelimiter("")` will return 1-length substring on `next()`, because an empty string does in fact sit between every two characters.

That is, because `"\r\n".equals("\r" + "" + "\n")` so `"\r\n"` are in fact two tokens, `"\r"` and `"\n"`, delimited by `""`.

To get the `Matcher`-behavior, you need `findWithinHorizon`, which ignores delimiters.

```
    Pattern newLinePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\r\\n?|\\n)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    String sourceString = "\r\n\n\r\r\n\n";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(sourceString);
    int count = 0;
    while (scan.findWithinHorizon(newLinePattern, 0) != null) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("found "+count+" newlines"); // finds 5 newlines
```

#### API links

- [`findWithinHorizon(Pattern pattern, int horizon)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.util.regex.Pattern,%20int%29)

  > Attempts to find the next occurrence of the specified pattern [...] ignoring delimiters [...] If no such pattern is detected then the `null` is returned [...] If `horizon` is 0, then [...] this method continues to search through the input looking for the specified pattern without bound.

#### Related questions

- [Scanner method to get a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597841/scanner-method-to-get-a-char)

  - `useDelimiter("")` will tokenize into 1-length substrings

Answer (score 3):

That is, in fact, the expected behaviour of both. The scanner primarily cares about splitting things into tokens using your delimiter. So it (lazily) takes your sourceString and sees it as the following set of tokens: `\r`, `\n`, `\n`, `\r`, `\r`, `\n`, and `\n`. When you then call hasNext it checks if the next token matches your pattern (which they all trivially do thanks to the `?` on the `\r\n?`). The while loop therefore iterates over each of the 7 tokens.

On the other hand, the matcher will match the regex greedily - so it bundles the `\r\n`s together as you expect.

One way to emphasise the behaviour of Scanner is to change your regexp to `(\\r\\n|\\n)`. This results in a count of 0. This is because the scanner reads the first token as `\r` (*not* `\r\n`), and then notices it doesn't match your pattern, so returns false when you call `hasNext`.

(Short version: the scanner tokenises using your delimiter before using your token pattern, the matcher doesn't do any form of tokenising)

Comment: So to use Scanner correctly, the function useDelimiter should be used with the newline pattern, then each call to next will give a line corresponding to the overloaded version of next used.

Comment: Just dug through Scanner.java to find that out. Now for the followup question: Is there a class that allows me to parse input based on regexs alone, not delimiting tokens also?

Comment: @SEK Well, you can use `Matcher` as you did in your example. Or you can just use your newLinePattern as the delimiter as Loki said :). (But note that this will mean you can't tell the difference between `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n` delimited lines, as far as I know - the scanner will just swallow the delimiters; if you desperately need them you could use something hideous like `(?<=\r)(?!\n)|(?<=\n)` as the delimiter, but I think I'd investigate better approaches before resorting to that... ;))

Comment: @Loki: Thank you both for the quick responses. Also check @polygenelubricants' solution, he hit it on the head.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth mentioning that your example is ambiguous. It could be:

```
\r
\n
\n
\r
\r
\n
\n
```

(seven lines)

or:

```
\r\n
\n
\r
\r\n
\n
```

(five lines)

The ? quantifier you have used is a greedy quantifier, which would probably make five the right answer, but because Scanner iterates over tokens (in your case individual characters, due to the delimiting pattern you chose), it will match reluctantly, one character at a time, arriving at the incorrect answer of seven.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `Scanner` with a delimiter of `""` it will produce tokens that are each one character long. This is before your new line regex is applied. It then matches each of these characters against the new line regex; each one matches, so it produces 7 tokens. However, because it split the string into 1-character tokens it will not group adjacent `\r\n` characters into one token.