# How to listen to keyboard events in a console application

Tags: java

Now, I'm developing a command-line application somewhat like bash. For implementing the autocomplete functionality, I must know users have pressed Tab key. But i don't know how to listen to keyboard events in a console application.

any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use KeyListener OR KeyAdapter event handlers. Example can be found at http://www.kodejava.org/examples/224.html

Comment: Then you can have a look at reading a character from console. Once you read this, you can find if it is TAB and can proceed further. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597841/scanner-method-to-get-a-char

Comment: Sounds feasible, I'll have a try, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly more complicated than it looks.

Maybe you should have a look at the [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) project that handles everything for you.