# How to invoke an action on keystroke or key binding

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to listen to keyboard events in a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075769/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-events-in-a-console-application)

Hi I am new to java syntax.I am trying to invoke an action on a keystroke like "ENTER key"

For ex:

```
on pressing Enter key {
    int c = 9+8 ;    //This should run on pressing enter key but not just running program directly
    printf("c");
}
```

I have referred few java doc relating to this and tried to execute the code.But I face few syntax errors. Can any one give direct example

Comment: Are you using java.awt? Can you specify technology name?

Comment: No. im running a console type program

Comment: Yes, but to capture "Enter" key press, you must have something like TextBox, TextArea etc. Which TextBox are you using? java.awt.TextField?

Comment: @user1677685 Have a look at this question: [How to listen to keyboard events in a console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075769/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-events-in-a-console-application)

Comment: @RAS Nope its a console program where it should read enter key and run the program and give output. Im new to java programming just wanted to try this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a command line application, I believe you'd have to parse input from `System.in`.  If you are only wanting to supply initial parameters, there are libraries out there that can do this for you to make your life easier such as [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/).  If you are running from the command line, you will be compiling your code to a .jar file.  This library should let you supply flags, and named arguments to your java classes within your jar file.

To output text to the command prompt, use System.out.