# Compare a char using equals

Tags: java

If I am scanning from a text

```
Scanner s= new Scanner("texto.txt");
```

// I want to compare the next char from the line with a `<`

// like this:

```
if(s.nextChar().equals("<")){
.....
```

I know that `s.nextChar()` does not exist but there is any similar thing to use in this case?

Comment: You could loop through the input using the substring method and compare that way? That's assuming the input is not limited to 1 character

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Scanner method to get a char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597841/scanner-method-to-get-a-char)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, note that `"<"` and `'<'` are two completely different things.

Comment: so, is your question about how to do comparison of char using equals, or how to use scanner to get next char?  Your title and actual question just don't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would something like...

```
Scanner s= new Scanner("texto.txt");
s.useDelimiter("");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    if(s.nextChar()=='<'){
 .....
}
```

Note that after the call of `s.nextChar()`, the value is actually fetched, so its better to keep the variable, if you would like to use it further, like:

```
char ch = s.nextChar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider dumping Scanner and using FileReader:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("textto.txt");

int charRead
while( (charRead = fileReader.read()) != -1)
{
   if(charRead == '<')
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      FileReader reader = null;
  try {
     reader = new FileReader("");
     int ch = reader.read() ; 
     while (ch != -1) {
        // check for your char here
     }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
     //
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     //
  } finally {
     try {
        reader.close();
     } catch (IOException ex) {
        //
     }
  }
```