# Getting a character as input from user using Scanner(System.in)

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a character from user as input from the keyboard, I couldn't able to find a way to read character from keyboard and store it in character array. Kindly help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Scanner` and the `findInLine` method:

```
Scanner inputTaker = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = inputTaker.nextLine();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
char someCharacter = scanner.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
// Do something with character
```

More here: [Scanner method to get a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597841/scanner-method-to-get-a-char)

Comment: If you've a similar question, then you should flag this question here as a duplicate, instead of answering it again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Java Scanner class to read in the next line and get the first character of that line.  Refer to this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner)

Comment: HI Mark,I tried that method to get the first character from the input string but it won't works...

Comment: Could you post your code so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: If you've a similar question, then you should flag this question here as a duplicate, instead of answering it again.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no need of creating a new instance once again for the Scanner class.

```
Scanner inputLine = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] charArray = inputLine.toCharArray();
System.out.println(charArray[0]);// 0 is used for example and you can use it based on your requirement.
```

Comment: I think you should try your own code, to make sure it really works ...

Comment: Now is more than a month gone ... have you already tested this code?