# change a scanner to a char variable instead of a int or double data type

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Player's Name: ");
        double n = kbr.nextInt();
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

Can I change this to

```
char n = kbr.nextInt()
```

or 
how can I get it to look for a `character` string instead of an `int`.

Comment: You can get a `String` with `kbr.next()`. [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) are your friend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner method to get a char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597841/scanner-method-to-get-a-char)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this as alternative:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
            Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter Player's Name: ");
            String n = kbr.readLine();
            //int z = Integer.parseInt();
            char z = n.charAt(0);
            System.out.print(n);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.printl("IO ERROR !!!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Player's Name: ");
        String n = kbr.nextLine();
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to get only first character of the typed string then

```
char c = kbr.next().charAt(0);
```

works fine.
However it allows to input more than single character but as soon as you hit enter,
it will store first character in `char c`.

### For example

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Character: ");
        char n = kbr.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

> Input: Hello
>
> Output: H