# Continuously get keyboard input from user and remember last character [Java]

Tags: java, swing, listener

I want to write a Snake game in Java. How can I continuously monitor input and if user pressed `W` set variable 
`Char lastDirection = 'w'; //hence, Direction.UP`?

I know about the `Scanner` method:  `Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);`...
But then user would have to hit enter each time he presses the button. Document Listener (Swing) seems better, but then i would have a long string of user input saved somewhere that I don't need. What is the right method for listening to keyboard and remembering the last character?

---

Answer to the "possible duplicate" question is irrelevant, because I was looking for a Swing compatible method, not a Console API. My question was probably marked as a "possible duplicate" using grep utility triggered by a keyword `Scanner`.

---

`KeyAdapter`works well with Swing components for this task. 
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/snake/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner method to get a char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597841/scanner-method-to-get-a-char). More specifically, see the second answer.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: `KeyAdapter` works well for this task. See http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/snake/